# scala reflection get class of enumaration value

Tags: scala, reflection, enumeration, classname

Assume we have

```
class User(val name: String, val role: UserRole.Value)

class UserRole extends Enumeration {
    val Admin, User = Value
}

val u = new User("root", UserRole.Admin)
```

how to get Class[_] "class UserRole" when

```
u.role.getClass
```

return "scala.Enumeration.Value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `new User("root", UserRole.Admin)` nor `role: UserRole.Value` make sense, because `UserRole` is not a value. Normally, `Enumeration` is extended by `object`s, not `class`es.

Something like

```
val field = classOf[Enumeration#Value].getDeclaredField("outerEnum")
field.setAccessible(true)
val enum = field.get(u.role)
enum.getClass // if you want specifically the class
```

should work (at least for the current versions; `outerEnum` is not part of the API!)

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.11 and I needed to use `getDeclaredField("scala$Enumeration$$outerEnum")` to make it work.